# Understanding image under set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

With three sets:

$A$ = {1, 2, 3}, $B$ = {4, 5, 6}, and $h$ = {(1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 5)}.

Could someone walk me through how to find the image under $h$ of each of the 8 subsets of $A$ and the inverse image of each of the 8 subsets of $B$.

Simple question trying to visualize the definition of image and inverse image. Thanks!

Comment: Can you write down the subsets of A and B?

Comment: @JohnDouma when it asks for the 8 subsets i assume one would be empty set. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. One of the sets is the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

If $A' \subseteq A$, then $h[A'] = \{h(x) : x \in A' \}$, by the definition. From the definition of $h$ (the set of pairs) we see that $h(1) = 4, h(2) = 4, h(3) = 5$. Now enumerate all 8 subsets of $A$ and compute the images. E.g. $h[A] = \{h(1), h(2), h(3)\} = \{4,4,5\} = \{4,5\}$ and so on.

If $B' \subseteq B$, then $h^{-1}[B'] = \{x \in A: h(x) \in B \}$. So the inverse image of of $B'$ is all those points of $A$ whose image lies in $B'$.

So without looking at $h$ we already know (as $h$ maps $A$ into $B$) that $h^{-1}[B] = A$ and also true for any function is $h^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$

But also $h^{-1}[\{4\}] = \{1,2\}$, as those are the points with image equal to $4$. You look at all subsets of $B$ in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

if $S \subset A$ then $f(S) = \{f(x)|x \in A\}$.

S of if A = {1} then f(A) = {f(1)} = {4}.  If A = {1,2} then f(A) = {f(1), f(2)} = {4}.  Etc.  etc. etc.